# The difference between "call gate" and "Software interrupt?

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, intel

These are safe, low-privilege ways to call kernel functions.

I don't know the difference between the two.

Answer (score 4):

You can look through the intel manuals for all the gory bits; but in a nutshell:

1. Call Gate does not disable interrupts.
2. Call Gate can copy N arguments between the stacks on a privity switch.
3. Call Gate can be LDT private
4. Call Gate can be disguised as a *normal* function pointer, if your compiler happens to support intel `medium,large` compilations models.
5. Given 4, a normal "ret" instruction undoes a call gate entry.
6. Almost nobody every used Call Gates.

whereas:

1. Interrupt gates disable interrupts.
2. Interrupt gates don't care about arguments.
3. The IDT is a global resource.
4. The invocation sequence for interrupts is pretty unique from functions.

Comment: Interrupt gates *may* keep interrupts enabled - it depends if they are declared as "interrupt" or as "trap" in the IDT. (I was spending days searching for a bug until I found this out...) Solaris (SunOS) was using "Call Gates" - at least in older versions. And according to Wikipedia, they were also commonly used in OS/2 and Windows 95.